# What is the symbol Å?

Tags: soft-question, units, frequency, notation, wavelength

I saw this symbol like:

$$\lambda=3000\overset{\circ}{\text{A}}$$

and I don't know what this means. Is it a frequency? (since $\lambda$ is usually used for frequency)

Comment: Note that $\lambda$ is usually *wavelength* not frequency, though the two concepts are related by the wave speed.

Comment: I've edited the tags accordingly, but I left [tag:frequency] because it would be kind of odd to have a question that reads as if it is about frequency without it.

Comment: In case you ever need to look up a letter/symbol, search it in Wikipedia, and usually they list the applications in mathematics and physics.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is an [ångström](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstrom), a unit of length commonly used in chemistry to measure things like atomic radii and bond lengths.  Although not an official [SI](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) unit, it has a simple relationship to the [metric units of length](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#SI_prefixed_forms_of_metre):

$$1\:\mathrm{ångström} = 1\:\mathrm{Å} = 10^{−10}\:\mathrm{m} = 0.1\:\mathrm{nm} = 100\:\mathrm{pm}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The angstrom was intended to be a tenth-metre, but because the definition being used was more exact than the metre at the time, and based on a mis-estimation of the Stockholm prototype, a different name is used.  In a similar vein, the X-Unit is defined as a thirteenth-metre, but also is out by some factor, so is not so called.

It was first used to measure spectral lines of the visible spectrum, but the length is convenient size for atoms and molecules.  A hydrogen atom has a diameter of 1.058 A.

Comment: What are you babbling about? Decimetres and thirteenth-metres? Go away.

Comment: a "tenth-meter" would be a decimeter, not an angstrom... You're making no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I suspect this is a translation issue, as "tenth-meter" likely corresponds to $10^{-10}$ here.  See [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenthmeter) for a dictionary example of the usage (though apparently the hyphen is omitted by convention.)

Comment: If the answer was all garbled due to Wendy's poor English skills, I apologize for being harsh, but her answer made absolutely no sense as written. 10^-10 m would make some sense, but what is "thirteenth-metre"? 10^-13 m?

Comment: @Phil, see [the X unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_unit), which is indeed approximately $10^{-13}m$.  Wendy has pointed out some subtleties here in that the angstrom was at one time only approximately a tenthmeter ($10^{-10}m$).  It is no longer approximate, but the historical fact of it having been so is a justification for why it has a different name.

Comment: @Phil, FYI, I did a bit of research and it looks like tenthmetre is still considered a valid unit name, equivalent to the modern angstrom (due to the change in definition of the metre.)  Given the 'metre' rather than 'meter' spelling in its most prevalent form, I'm guessing it's not used much in American English.

Comment: Ordinals in front of units means a repeat of units such as seconds = second minutes.  In CGS the repeats are divide by 10.  So a tenth metre ie 1 metre / 10^10.